# Prove that $D, F,$ and $G$ are collinear

Tags: geometry

Quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a rectangle.  The points $E$ and $G$ are the midpoints of $DC$ and $BC$ respectively.  The point $F$ is the intersection of the diagonal $AC$ and $BE$.  Prove that $D, F,$ and $G$ are collinear.[image]

I have included a sketch of the problem.  You can see where I constructed an extension of $AB$ and a line through the points $DG$ which intersects $AB$ at $I$.  I can show that $BGI$ and $DGC$ are congruent triangles by $ASA$, but I am not sure how to show that $D, F,$ and $G$ are collinear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be the point of intersection of $AC$ and $BD$. By ASA criteria (how?), we have that $\triangle CPB \cong \triangle APD$. Thus $PB=PD$, which means $CP$ is the median of $\triangle BCD$.

By using the fact that the medians coincide at the centroid, we have that $CP, BE, DG$ coincide at the centroid, which is given to be $F$, as the intersection of $CP$ and $BE$. Thus, $D, F$ and $G$ are collinear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the intercept theorem repeatedly.
$$ CF:FA=EF:FB=CE:AB=1:2$$
and with $F'=DI\cap AC$
$$ CF':F'A=DF':F'I=CD:AI=1:2$$
Hence $F'=F$.

Comment: We haven't learned anything about the intercept theorem yet.  We are basically only allowed to use what we've learned, so different theorems about congruent triangles, the parallel postulate, midsegments, etc.